# How can I do increase to datagridview header color and column hiding performance?

Tags: c#, winforms

If I use such a these usage for Datagridview HeaderText and HeaderColor, the loading performance is so badly even only there is four column.

I have only 20 row data in database. I have 7 column in total. But I'm hiding 3 column such as below method in Form_Load event. (And then I tried use in datagridview_DataBindingComplete event method but not so big change)

```
public void HideColumns()
{
     datagridview.Columns[COLUMN_INDEX].Visible = false;

     // ... 2 more assignments for set false to column visible ...
}
```

and

```
public void SetColumnsHeaderText()
{
     datagridview.Columns[COLUMN_INDEX].HeaderText = "Header Text";

     // .. 5 more assignments for set name to HeaderText
}
```

But if I don't call these method in Load or DataBindingComplete event program running faster. What can I do for increase performance the set color and name?

Datagridview already there and I only data binding with the datagridview.Datasource assignment.

**EDIT:** I tried everything and I found reason for bad performance. In SetColumnsHeaderText() methods assignments so expensive. What do you suggest for this issue?

Comment: I populate from database (e.g datagridview.Datasource = classNameDAL.GetRelatedData()) and problem is not about the queries or other database operations. I said this because I tried every situtation with use time. If I call the especially SetColumnsHeaderText() method then slowing down (When I call the setting and hiding methods loading takes 700ms. But I don't use these methods and only call the set datagridview datasource method then only 7 ms).

Comment: Are you creating the grid view dynamically/ it's already there and you are just binding the values and the columns that you are hiding, can they change based on DB value or you always hide the same columns?

Comment: You can apply these settings right after you have assigned the DataSource. What takes time is if you have set the `AutoSizeColumnMode = AllCells` and similar for `AutoSizeRowMode`. There might be some other events involved that you're not showing here. With DataSources much larger than what you have, the difference is negligible when hiding or setting the Headers Text, unless there are other formatting options in place.

Comment: It's already there and I just binding the values from database then hiding columns and set headers new name. Especially header text modifying take more time. What can I do or why header text more slowly? @Kurubaran

Comment: Try setting `AutoSizeColumnMode` and `AutoSizeRowMode` to `None`, for starters.

Comment: I tried past and 70-100 ms changed, but still SetColumnsHeaderText() takes average 600 ms. Most important issue headers name for me now and I can't find reason @Jimi

Comment: It would really help everyone if you showed you're actual code, from where you set the DataSource to the complete methods that re-define the Headers, plus some detail on your DataGridView properties. Also, clearly say whether or not you have subscribed to other events of the DGV.

Comment: @Jimi I find just now reason for the bad performance. I'm set the 6 column header text. I respectively try the comment in and out headerText assignment. Every headerText assignment process commented out takes a more time. Only problem is datagridview.Columns[index].HeaderText = "HeaderName" assignment. This is reason for my performance problem.

Comment: Try setting `AutoSizeColumnMode` and `AutoSizeRowMode` to `None`, then  `dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);` right after you have modified the Headers.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for all contributions. I solved problem just now via Data Annotation (DisplayName).

Comment: @CeyhunSoft Please don't write the answer as part of the question. You can post an answer. Also always share [MCVE] for your questions so other users can reproduce the problem and understand what the problem you are trying to solve.